# OrientDB how to get a result set of vertices and its edges in one query

Tags: sql, orientdb, graph-databases

I have been playing around with OrientDB sql queries to get a result set that contains not only vertices but also the internal edges that exists between them.

The query could be expressed as:

- I want all the vertices that are related to `project` (without project itself) and all the edges between the vertices that are included in the results

[image]

Here is how I have achieved it but I think it is not the proper way to do it.

[image]

`select expand($union) let $vertices = ( select from ( traverse both() from (select from V where label = 'project') ) skip 1 ), $edges = ( select from ( select from E where @rid in ( select bothE() from ( select from ( traverse both() from (select from V where label = 'project') ) skip 1 ) ) ) where out in ( select from ( traverse both() from (select from V where label = 'project') ) skip 1 ) and in in ( select from ( traverse both() from (select from V where label = 'project') ) skip 1 ) ), $union = unionall($vertices, $edges)`

**And the expected results:**

[image]

**Problems with this solution:**

- I have to traverse the graph multiple times (first to get the vertices and then to get the edges to finally merge the results)
- The base query `select from V where label = 'project'` is also executed several times.

Is there a better way to solve this use case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select expand($c)
let $a=(traverse both(),bothE() from (select from V where label="project")),
$b=(traverse bothE() from (select from V where label="project")),
$c=difference($a,$b)
```

Comment: Wow, that looks a lot simpler. If it works, nice work!

Comment: Thank you very much Michela!. It works as expected and there is a huge performance improvement with this query. In a graph with ~3300 sphere vertices my query takes ~4.8s while yours only ~0.15s. :-)

Comment: Is it possible to store the result of `select from V where label="project"` and use it in the both traverse operations?

Comment: @aschiavoni, I didn't test it, but the following should work `select expand($c) from (select from V where label="project" limit 1)
let $a=(traverse both(),bothE() from $parent),
$b=(traverse bothE() from $parent),
$c=difference($a,$b)` You may need to swap `$parent` for `$current`, or even `$parent.$current`. I also added in the limit, which is a good habit for such a query.